# Process unkown number of form elements

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms

Disclaimer: This might be a general web development question and not specifically a wtforms question.

I am tinkering with a private [gist](https://gist.github.com/) clone written with [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and friends.

I have created a form with the help from [Wtforms](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WTForms/) for creating a new item/file:

```
# forms.py

from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, SelectField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers

LEXER_CHOICES = []
for name, aliases, filetypes, mimetypes_ in [x for x in get_all_lexers()]:
    LEXER_CHOICES.append((aliases[0], name))

class NewItem(Form):

    description = TextField('description')
    content = TextAreaField('content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    lexer = SelectField('lexer', choices=sorted(LEXER_CHOICES))
    filename = TextField('filename')
```

Please see the screenshot below for the output.

With just this - it is working fine (creating, rendering and validating the form).

Now I want to refactor Instead of just be able to define one new file/item - I want to be able to assign multiple files/items for a newly created collection of files.

=> Just like "gist" does.

So by clicking "+ Add" I want to clone the form above and reset the values on the client side.

I do not worry about the client side...

My question is: Is there a common pattern form Wtforms to accomplish this (so I still have the validation mechanisms in place)?

Do I have to revise my form design?

---

[image: the form]

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402627/how-to-get-a-build-a-form-with-repeated-elements-well) - if the linked question and answer are not clear, just edit your question to explain what additional problems you are having and I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the duplicate: Field Enclosures (http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=enclosures#field-enclosures) seems to be answer.